$\mathfrak{p}$-adic valuation of a norm
Given extension of Number fields L/K and prime ideal $\mathfrak{P} \in O_L$ lying over $\mathfrak{p} \in O_K$. Let $\hat{L}$ and $\hat{K}$ be the completions of L and K respectively. And let e and f be the ramification indices.
I want to show that $v_{\mathfrak{P}}(N_{\hat{L}/\hat{K}}(x))= |\hat{L}:\hat{K}|  v_{\mathfrak{P}}(x)$.
My first idea is to write the norm as the product of $|\hat{L}:\hat{K}|=ef$ $\hat{K}$-embeddings of $\hat{L}$ into a normal closure. But I am not sure how to finish as if $\hat{L} / \hat{K}$ is not normal then some of terms in this product are not in $\hat{L}$ so I cannot take the product.
Any ideas on how to proceed? Thanks

If you can solve the Galois case, one trick is to consider the Galois closure $N / L / K$, consider a prime ideal $\mathfrak{Q} \in O_N$ lying above $\mathfrak{P} \in O_L$, and prove the statement you want for the extension $N/L$ and $N/K$. Transitivity of norm should allow you to conclude afterwards.
